# select option in webview before charge in android app

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, android-studio

I want select an option in webview before load it?

```
 private fun injectJavaScript(view: WebView): Boolean {view.loadUrl("javascript:$('.game').val('pica');"+
            "})()")return true
}
```

this is my code in android studio

```
<select class="game">
  <option value="pica" selected="" data-src="http://.png" >Pica</option>
  <option value="stat" data-src="http://.png" >Stat</option>
</select>
```

and this web page

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
$('.game option[value="pica"]').prop("selected", true); 

private fun injectJavaScript(view: WebView): Boolean {view.loadUrl("javascript:$('.game option[value=\"pica\"]').prop(\"selected\", true);"+
        "})()")return true
}
```

Comment: @limdnaslimdnas I've updated the answer, have a look

Comment: same result, dont change option, i can delete footer with:  view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];"
                + "footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer);" +
                "})()")  , but i cant 
load webpage with the option changed, i try to delete all others options and i cant do it

Comment: here you have all, how i can change this options?

Comment: @limdnaslimdnas Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/3hhv3qrj/15/ and since your are referring to class, you need to access a class by `.` . Please check the JS code